# How does Transactions work in Ethereum Virtual Machine?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, addresses, evm

While reading the [transactions sections](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#index-8) of EVM documentation many questions raised in my head:

> If the target account is not set (the transaction does not have a
>   recipient or the recipient is set to null), the transaction creates a
>   new contract **(The payload should be the code of the contract,
>   correct ? ).**  As already mentioned, the address of that contract is
>   not the zero address but an address derived from the sender and its
>   number of transactions sent (the “nonce”) **(But Doesn't the nonce
>   represent a number that combined with block data provides the hash of
>   the next block ? )** . The payload of such a contract creation
>   transaction is taken to be EVM bytecode and executed **(Do they mean
>   the compiled bytecode of the contract ? and what do they mean by "and
>   executed" ? )** . The output data of this execution is permanently
>   stored as the code of the contract. This means that in order to create
>   a contract, you do not send the actual code of the contract, but in
>   fact code that returns that code when executed **(Which code returns
>   what ? We have contract code and the compiled contract I missed this
>   one entirely ) .**

Sorry for embedding the question the quote but I think this is for better understanding what I really when asking the questions.

Comment: Partial answer: There are two kinds of nonces. Every block has a nonce which is randomly generated in the mining process. Every address has a nonce, which is incremented every time it sends a transaction. It guarantees that transactions are ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/09/how-smart-contract-deployment-works/ answers all of these questions.

Regarding the code that's deployed:

> The data field of a contract deployment transaction is code *to be
>   executed during contract initialization*. It is not the code that is
>   executed on subsequent transactions sent to the contract. That code is
>   *returned* by the initialization code. Essentially, the code in the data
>   field is a program that is going to write a program that gets deployed
>   as a smart contract. Although that sounds fairly open-ended and
>   complex, in practice it is typically quite straightforward. The
>   standard initialization code generated by the Solidity compiler does
>   the following:
>
> 1. Runs the code in the contract’s constructor, setting storage values,
>      etc.
> 2. *Copies* the code for the rest of the contract into memory and
>      returns it. The code to be copied is simply appended to the
>      constructor’s code in the data field.
>
> Constructor parameters are handled similarly. They are stored last in
>   the data field, and the initialization code reads them from there.

Regarding the nonce, it's a per-account nonce, not the nonce used in the block headers:

> Once a contract is deployed, it is referenced by its address, which is guaranteed to be unique. Computing the address requires only the address of the sender account and the sender’s nonce.